# Frontal Area of buildings using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, elevation, building-heights

I have to calculate the frontal area index of buildings in a city (λf) which is the total area of buildings projected into the plane normal to the wind direction (Aproj) divided by the ground plan area. I have a 1-m resolution buildings height raster.

Any ideas on how to do that using QGIS?

I cannot find an algorithm to calculate the frontal area.

[image]

> Source:  Burian, Steven J., Michael J. Brown, and Steve P. Linger.
> "Morphological analyses using 3D building databases: Los Angeles,
> California." Los Alamos National Laboratory 74 (2002).

Comment: Well, this seems to be a basic geometric problem: What have you tried to solve it? What data besides the building height do you have?

Comment: I just have the Digital Elevation Model of the entire city and the building heights.   
I looked for an algorithm to calculate the frontal area of a building first but did not find anything relevant. Does QGIS allow for such calculation?

Comment: It'd be easier if you had the building outlines with the heigth attached.

Comment: I found that. I have a map of the buildings with the height of each one.

Comment: Do you have a map, or a shapefile?